# Magento Backend Login does not open

Tags: magento

I suppose my domain was hacked & had over 55 admins in the backend. I did not know what I had to do, I deleted the role Admin from Configuration - permissions - roles.

Now, we are unable to login into our back-end. Please advice on what can be done & how ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: kindly try to create a admin user programatically.

Comment: Try this link. https://santoshyadavcse.wordpress.com/2013/02/04/magento-create-admin-user-programmatically/

Comment: SUPEE-5344 installation delayed, so there probably are no good backups. There is nothing trustworthy left, rebuild from scratch if you value your customers.